# I am trying to make my php main class compress and use it like normal php code

Tags: php, encoding, decode, compression

I don't want to give my code to client. I know there is no any such way which make my code 100% secure from client or editing by other developers but at least i think from may clients i can hide my code, for this i am using the following way:

For example, I have the following code:

```
$php = base64_encode('<?php function add($a,$b){echo($a+$b);} add(30,40); ?>');
```

The above line produces the following code of my php code:

```
PD9waHAgZnVuY3Rpb24gYWRkKCRhLCRiKXtlY2hvKCRhKyRiKTt9IGFkZCgzMCw0MCk7ID8+
```

I used gzencode() method to compress the above generated code like this:

```
$txt = "PD9waHAgZnVuY3Rpb24gYWRkKCRhLCRiKXtlY2hvKCRhKyRiKTt9IGFkZCgzMCw0MCk7ID8+";
$ph = gzencode($txt,8);
```

I can get the Original php code by using the following code:

```
echo(base64_decode($ph));
```

It produces:

```
<?php function add($a,$b){echo($a+$b);} add(30,40); ?>
```

Now, this code shows in the source code in the browser but i want to run this code like the original php code, so, what i have to do to make this executable?

Thanks

Comment: why even bother? if your "encryption" is just base64/gzip, then it's utterly pointless to even try. just leave it as regular code and slap a copyright notice on the code. that'll give you far more protection than a system that your basic cereal box decoder ring would be better at. If you insist on doing this, then use `eval()`.

Comment: Thanks Marc B, i am living in the country where there no punishment for piracy. therefore i am trying to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *eval* to run the string as inline code. Check this ([eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php#108091))
You can also create an anonymous function which your string code should be inside ([create_function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php))

Comment: Keep in mind that this type of obfuscation will decrease application performance, possibly quite significantly, and will make opcode caches unable to accelerate your application.

Comment: Actually i want to keep my one class file protected from clients edit/update.